# React (native) testing asyncStorage call mock function

Tags: react-native, mocking, react-testing-library, react-query, asyncstorage

I'm having trouble testing if a function has been called (storeToken) on React Query (onSuccess)

React Query useMutation:

```
const mutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: async (body: LoginBody) => await login(body),
    onSuccess: async (res) => {
     ** await storeToken(res.data.token)**
    },
  })
```

Login response (msw handler):

```
res(
      ctx.delay(1000),
      ctx.status(200),
      ctx.json({ token: MOCKED_TOKEN })
    )
```

The function:

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage"

export const storeToken = async (token: string) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", token)
  } catch (e) {
    return e
  }
}
```

The test:

```
import { storeToken } from "../../utils"

jest.mock("../../utils", () => ({
  storeToken: jest.fn(),
}))

describe("When Login form is submited correctly", () => {
 it("should fetch login with email and password and save token on response status 200", async () => {
    renderWithProviders(<LoginScreen />)

    fireEvent.changeText(getEmailInput(), "email@email.com")
    fireEvent.changeText(getPasswordInput(), "123456")

    fireEvent.press(getSubmitBtn())

  
    await waitFor(()=>expect(storeToken).toHaveBeenCalled())
  })
})
```

I tried mocking AsyncStorage but I got the same reult